# How do I write binary data to a text file in Python?

Tags: python, binary-data, file-format

I need to write text, then binary data to a file. For example, I would like to write the file with contents:

```
BESTFORMAT
NUMLINES 42
FIELDS FOO BAR SPAM
DATATYPES INT32 FLOAT64 FLOAT64
FILETYPE BINARY
???d?'Ӈ T???'Ѥ??X??\??
?? R??&??X??\???????
??zR??X??\????????
...
```

However, in Python you can't open a file in a way that you can write ASCII data, then binary data.

---

I've tried:

- Converting my binary data to text (no good, as it outputs `b'5 42.7 0.8'`
- Encoding my text data to binary and opening the file as binary (no good, as then I have a binary file). Edit: it turns out this was working, but I needed to open the file in my text editor with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python how to write to a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367007/python-how-to-write-to-a-binary-file)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple solutions:

1. Write text data, then re-open in append binary mode and write binary data

```py
with open("file", "w") as f:
    f.write("text")
with open("file", "ab") as f:
    f.write(b"bytes")
```

2. Convert the text data to bytes

```py
with open("file", "wb") as f:
    f.write("text".encode())
    f.write(b"bytes")
```

3. Write the text data to a text wrapper

```py
import io
with open("file", "wb") as f:
    f_text = io.TextIOWrapper(f, write_through=True)
    f_text.write("text")
    f.write(b"bytes")
```

Note: some text editors will see non-utf-8 bytes in the file and view the file in hexadecimal mode. To see the text, re-open the file in the text editor in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: you could have used `fl.write(b"BESTFORMAT\n\
NUMLINES 42\n\
FIELDS FOO BAR SPAM\n\
DATATYPES INT32 FLOAT64 FLOAT64\n\
FILETYPE BINARY\n\
")` so you could have used the binary mode of the file